# Python regexp capture multi line groups

Tags: python, regex

Given this string:

```
@@@@ foo foo
@@@@ bar bar
bla bla bla

@@@@ one two test
@@@@ test one two
bla bla bla bla
```

is it possible with a Python regex to capture the multi line groups of lines starting with `@@@@`?

Expected result:

```
group1: '@@@@ foo foo\n@@@@ bar bar\n'
group2: '@@@@ one two test\n@@@@ test one two'
```

I am trying with:

`(@@@@ [A-Za-z]+)`

But I got 4 different groups indeed.

Comment: Looks like `re.findall` with `r"(?:@{4}.*?(?:\n|$))+"` should work for oyu.

Comment: And it does! Thank you!

Comment: @carloratm You actually should anchor the match at the start of the line and there is no need making the dot lazy since it does not match an LF symbol. See my answer below.

Comment: Glad [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50562186/3832970) worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
(?m)^@{4}.*(?:\n@{4}.*)*\n?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qSMe8o/1/).

**Details**

- `(?m)` - `re.MULTILINE` inline option
- `^` - start of a line
- `@{4}` - 4 `@` chars
- `.*` - the whole line up to LF (inclusing CR)
- `(?:\n@{4}.*)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

  - `\n` - a newline LF
  - `@{4}` - four `@` chars
  - `.*` - the rest of the line
- `\n?` - an optional LF (use `*` instead of `?` to match 0 or more repetitions)

Note it also works with CRLF endings.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/bIoTAi):

```
import re
rx = r"(?m)^@{4}.*(?:\n@{4}.*)*\n?"
s = "@@@@ foo foo\n@@@@ bar bar\nbla bla bla\n\n@@@@ one two test\n@@@@ test one two\nbla bla bla bla"
s2 = "@@@@ foo foo\r\n@@@@ bar bar\r\nbla bla bla\r\n\r\n@@@@ one two test\r\n@@@@ test one two\r\nbla bla bla bla"
print(re.findall(rx, s))
# => ['@@@@ foo foo\n@@@@ bar bar\n', '@@@@ one two test\n@@@@ test one two\n']
print(re.findall(rx, s2))
# => ['@@@@ foo foo\r\n@@@@ bar bar\r\n', '@@@@ one two test\r\n@@@@ test one two\r\n']
```